# Get all startup projects in solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, vsix

As the title suggests I want to query all the Startup Projects set in a `IVsSolution/IVsHierarchy`, also I would love to achieve that without the `DTE` needed. Therefor `DTE2.Solution.SolutionBuild.StartupProjects` isn't really a suitable option for me. I have look into the MSDN, but didn't find quite what I needed. I came across the [`IVsSolutionManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionbuildmanager?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) with its [`get_StartupProject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionbuildmanager.get_startupproject?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsSolutionBuildManager_get_StartupProject_Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsHierarchy__) method. Unfortunately it will only return a *single* startup project. Is this even doable with using the `DTE`?

Comment: If you can find all the project files from the SLN file, you can inspect the contents of the CSPROJ file and see if its outputting a EXE or DLL. EXEs can be startup projects.

Comment: @JamesFaix I do not want to get the _theoretical_ startup projects. I am trying to get the actual ones.

Comment: There's only one startup project.

Comment: @3Dave - not according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2019

Comment: @VladFeinstein I stand corrected! Thanks for the link.

Comment: See if this helps:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817693/how-do-i-programmatically-find-out-the-action-of-each-startup-project-in-a-solut

Comment: @VladFeinstein `IVsPersistSolutionProps` seems to be very promising, I'll check it out later. Thanks for now!

Comment: @VladFeinstein sadly I do not see anyway how I would get the startup projects by `IVsPersistSolutionProps`. Since I can't see a way on how I would get this interface. Actually I figured it out, but I am stuck on what to pass the [IVsPersistSolutionOpts.ReadUserOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivspersistsolutionopts.readuseroptions?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsPersistSolutionOpts_ReadUserOptions_Microsoft_VisualStudio_OLE_Interop_IStream_System_String_) method.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. However, this guy appears to have a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618573/visual-studio-get-the-startup-project-programmatically/37622771#37622771

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears, the EnvDTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.StartupProjects is the only way to do this. I did a walk through of the underlying VS IDE code base, and the startup projects are denoted by an internal flag on an internal C++ class tracking all the loaded projects. Unfortunately, neither that particular class or it's m_dwStartupOpt member are directly (or indirectly exposed.

So your best/only option here is to use that StartupProjects property.

Sincerely,

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer. Anyhow it is really sad though, I really thought I could do it by using the [`VsPersistSolutionOpts.ReadUserOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivspersistsolutionopts.readuseroptions?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsPersistSolutionOpts_ReadUserOptions_Microsoft_VisualStudio_OLE_Interop_IStream_System_String_) method. Unfortunately I do not know what I should pass for the `IStream` parameter.

Comment: It might be possible, if the projects have persisted when you go to read the options. But the best/easiest solution is through that StartupProjects property. For what it's worth, it's utilized quite a bit in our own codebase. So there's really no need to "avoid" it.

Comment: I guess that's the only option. Whatever thanks for your help!

Comment: How do you get from StartUpProject to the actual Project's BuildOutputDirectory. Is there some way to get the StartUpProject's (assuming there is only 1) Project object?